# How do I workaround invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in ruby text file parsing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, utf-8

I'm doing some analytics on my rails logs files. Mid-way through I get this error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

This is my (simplified) code, which is a rake task:

```
namespace :app do

  desc 'import the records'
  task :import => [ :environment ] do 

    File.open(LOGFILE).each_line do |line|  #reads chunks
      do_stuff(line)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: which ruby version are you using?

Comment: since you are already on ruby 2, you shouldnt have problems upgrading to 2.1.0. Ruby 2.1 has String#scrub that does exactly that: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scrub. Use 2.1.0 or 2.1.2+ (not 2.1.1). 2.1.1 has a bug with Hash

Comment: had all kinds of trouble installing 2.1 + on my system. Ended up going with this gem that backports the scrub method:gem 'string-scrub', '0.0.3' #this backports the ruby 2.1.0 method that removes invalid byte sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with this gem that backports the scrub method:gem 'string-scrub'